# Как изменить язык подсказок PHP Manual в Netbeans 8 на русский язык?

Tags: php

Как изменить язык подсказок из `PHP` документации в `Netbeans 8`?

Проще говоря, нужно чтобы при написании кода были подсказки из файла `php_manual_ru.chm`, `php_enhanced_ru.chm` или в онлайн режиме с сайта http://php.net/manual/ru/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `phpDocumentor`

1. Tools / Plugins
2. Установить `phpDocumentor`

[Офиц. сайт](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/ric_INSTALL.html).

Comment: Спасибо, изначально думал что это не совсем то что надо. Оказалось то, буду разбираться